# Bad format for date, time, timestamp or interval literal in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

I am trying to check whether my current time stamp falls between two-time stamps.

I am using the following query in my Oracle StoredProcedure

```
IF(SYSDATE BETWEEN TRUNC ( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '17:50' HOUR TO MINUTE AND TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '18:30' HOUR TO MINUTE) THEN
```

But it is giving me following error

```
Error(138,42): PLS-00166: bad format for date, time, timestamp or interval literal
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trunc(sysdate)` is a date, as opposed to a timestamp. Unfortunately, Oracle is weird this way: Date arithmetic works with numbers (and ONLY with numbers), while timestamps work with intervals. You can't add or subtract an interval to (from) a date.

Worse:  `trunc(systimestamp)` is a DATE and not a TIMESTAMP! If you want to know why, you will have to ask Oracle; I have no clue why.

The solution though is simple. Instead of `interval '17:50' hour to minute`, add `17/24 + 50/(24*60)`.

Or, you could cast `trunc(sysdate)` to a timestamp: `cast(trunc(sysdate) as timestamp)` - then the rest should work.

**ADDED**: As the OP points out, casting sysdate to timestamp did not cure the problem. I tried again, with different INTERVAL literals. While `INTERVAL '17:50' HOUR TO MINUTE` did not work, the full format `INTERVAL '0 17:50:00' DAY TO SECOND` did work (!!!)  It seems as if PL/SQL does not recognize partial INTERVAL formats and requires the full `DAY TO SECOND`. Something to check in the PL/SQL definition/documentation.

... OK, after further checking in the Oracle documentation: There is no specific mention of HOUR TO MINUTE not being supported; but it doesn't appear anywhere. Only DAY TO SECOND is mentioned. (In general, documentation will only show what is implemented, not what is NOT implemented, so this is not weird in any way.)

Comment: I tried IF(SYSDATE BETWEEN CAST(TRUNC ( SYSDATE ) AS TIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '17:50' HOUR TO MINUTE AND CAST(TRUNC( SYSDATE ) AS TIMESTAMP)+ INTERVAL '18:30' HOUR TO MINUTE) THEN

Comment: IF(SYSDATE BETWEEN TRUNC ( SYSDATE )  +17/24 + 50/(24*60) AND TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + 18/24 + 30/(24*60)) THEN

Comment: @Santosh - see what I added to the Answer; getting closer to a full answer to your question!

Comment: Ohh that's an awesome explanation.Great knowledge sharing.Very much helpful and Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Interesting - the expression works as posted in a SQL query but not in a PL/SQL `if` expression or similar. So date arithmetic with intervals is fine but only within a query. In PL/SQL there are arbitrary restrictions as some constructions work and some don't :(

Answer (score 1):

In PLSQL only DAY TO SECOND can be used.
You can use one of the following:

```
begin
    IF(SYSDATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '0 16:00:00' DAY TO SECOND
                     AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '0 18:00:00' DAY TO SECOND
    --IF(SYSDATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) + to_dsinterval('0 16:00:00')
    --               AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + to_dsinterval('0 18:00:00')
    )
    THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('now:'||sysdate); --now:01.03.2018 16:41:07
    end if;
end;
/
```

Please consider the following:

**SQL**

```
select interval '0 4'       day to hour  as ci from dual;          --+00 04:00:00.000000

select interval '0 4:10'    day to minute  as ci from dual;       --+00 04:10:00.000000

select interval '4:10'      hour to minute  as ci from dual;      --+00 04:10:00.000000

select interval '4:10:15'   hour to second  as ci from dual;      --+00 04:10:15.000000

select interval '0 4:10:15' day  to second as ci  from dual;       --+00 04:10:15.000000
```

**PLSQL**

```
declare

  --ci  CONSTANT INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := interval '0 4'       day to  hour;      --PLS-00103

  --ci  CONSTANT INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := interval '0 4:10'    day to  minute;    --PLS-00166

  --ci  CONSTANT INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := interval '4:10'      hour to  minute;   --PLS-00166  

  --ci  CONSTANT INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := interval '4:10:15'   hour to  second;   --PLS-00166  

  ci  CONSTANT INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := interval '0 4:10:15' day to  second;    --[+00 04:10:15.000000] 

begin 
  dbms_output.put_line('['||ci||']'); 
end;
/
--PLS-00166:  bad format for  date, time, timestamp or interval literal
--PLS-00103:  Encountered the symbol "HOUR" when expecting  one of the  following: second
```

Comment: I wouldn't use **trunc(sysdate) + 18/24 + 30/(24*60)**.
**trunc(sysdate) + interval '0 18:30:00' day to second** is more readable.

Comment: See Oracle Built-in Datatypes:
The interval datatypes are INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH and INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND. 

**INTERVAL YEAR [(year_precision)] TO MONTH** and
**INTERVAL DAY [(day_precision)] TO SECOND [(fractional_seconds)]**